# Is the opposite of the Cantor's Intersection Theorem True?

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I was trying to prove that in a metric space, if any sequence of nested closed metric balls such that their radius converges to zero has non-empty intersection, then the space is complete. But I couldn't.

Comment: English-speaking mathematicians use the word "any" too much. "If any sequence is etc.etc." can reasonably be construed as "If there is any sequence that is etc.etc." But here you probably meant "every". Just writing "every" instead of "any" is simple and completely disambiguates the sentences.

Answer (score 2):

If a metric space $X$ is not complete then there exists a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$ that does not converge. Let $\bar{X}$ be the completion of $X$ and let $a \in \bar{X} \setminus X$ be the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$. Pass to a subsequence $(a_m)$ such that $d(a_m, a)$ is decreasing. Then the sequence of nested closed sets
$$ A_m = \{x \in X : d(x, a) \leq d(a_m, a)\} \subset X$$
has empty intersection and their radius converges to zero.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this does not really answer your question since you were asking for balls, and not just closed sets. To obtain balls from this construction, I guess one should choose the same subsequence, but instead consider balls with very carefully chosen radii around the points in the sequence. The sets
$$ B_m = \{x \in X : d(x, a_m) \leq d(a_m , a) + 2^{-n}\}$$
should work, if I am not mistaken again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It is not clear in what sense these are closed *balls* in $X$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo They are not, I misread the question. Let me try to fix this.